# How can I emulate php's json_encode in javascript / node js using JSON.stringify?

Tags: php, json, node.js, stringify

I'm looking for a way to mimic php's json_encode's behavior from node js.  Here's an example showing what php does with a url that is in an object that gets json_encoded:

```
<?
$foo['url'] = "http://example.com/note/that/the/slashes/get/backslashed";
echo json_encode($foo);
?>
```

generates the following output:

```
{"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/note\/that\/the\/slashes\/get\/backslashed"}
```

Using node.js and the JSON.stringify function here:

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.url = "http://example.com/note/that/the/slashes/do/not/get/backslashed"
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

I observe this output instead:

```
 {"url":"http://example.com/note/that/the/slashes/do/not/get/backslashed"}
```

*Do you know of a clean way to get JSON.stringify to behave the same way that PHP behaves?*

Extra information: I realize that these slashes may not be required for correct json encoding but I am sending json encoded objects to a remote server that I don't have control over and doesn't like them without the backslashes.

More extra information:  And I tried putting in my own backslashes and then calling JSON.stringify but JSON.stringify dutifully does properly escape the backslashes so I ended up with \\/ instead of \/ which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only the slashes you can replace the `/` with `\/` *after* the conversion.

Comment: Ha!  How did I not see that?  Thanks!